Movie about an awful UK school, bullying & gangs
I was looking for a movie that was released between 2010 an 2012 I think, at least in Spain. 
I don't remember too many details of the movie, but I remember that the action was centered around a boy that is some kind of bully in an awful UK school. I think the film context was on a British place around 70's or 80's with some gangs and drug things.
The end of the movie is the main character running with a character that is like his friend but are not in good terms due to the morally bad actions of the main character along the movie. They end up on some kind of zoo surrounded by Lions at the sunrise.

I think this is Neds (2010)

Encompassed by violent street gangs, neglectful parents, bullying teachers and a dearth of positive role models, a studious but emotionally abandoned kid turns thug.






Neds follows the story of John McGill, a young boy growing up in 1970s Glasgow. While a brilliant student who excels in his studies at school, his studious nature causes conflicts with his working-class family and the wider, gang-riddled neighbourhood.
The film opens with a leaving ceremony marking John's transition from primary to secondary school. On his final day, John is accosted by Canta, a local bully and member of the Hardridge Parka Gang, who intimidates him, threatening to beat him up when he moves to secondary school. John relays the details of the encounter to his brother who enlists the help of his fellow gang members to track down and assault Canta as punishment.
...
He chooses to change his ways and returns to school, attending a remedial class, wanting no further involvement with the gang. The class goes on a field trip to a safari park and their minibus breaks down. Thinking the teachers have abandoned him with the brain-damaged Brown, John decides to leave the van. The film closes with John and Brown walking hand-in-hand into the distance through a pride of lions, who ignore them.
Wikipedia


That's it, thank you very much!! I looked over the wikipedia pages for movies between 20010 and 2012 and didn't found it.
